# When do I host different applications on the same application pool in IIS?

Tags: iis

It can be hosted more than one application in one application pool. That's what I know, but can we say every application should be hosted on a different application pool?

When can I use the same application pool for a different application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the same application pool for more than one application is possible - though you need to take into account some aspects:

- security context
  IF an app needs a different setup security-wise it goes into a different pool
- resource usage
  IF an app takes lots of resources it might be better to use a separate pool
- restart scenarios
  IF an app has different cycle etc. regarding restart (like updates etc) it might be better to use a different pool
- inter-application communication performance
  IF two or more apps need to communicate very intensely it might be better performance-wise to have them in the same pool.
- stability
  IF an app is much less stable than the others then it should go into a different pool

In all other cases it is more a question of ease of administration (for example one app pool per site) whether to use the same app pool or not...

Comment: Should the back end and front end of an application use the same application pool in your opinion? I want to store an Angular app backed by .NET Core in IIS.

Answer (score 5):

If you are on a low-end server, you can sometime save a little RAM by using the same application pool. Also, if you just have static webpages, you may be okay by them sharing the same application pool (as they rarely have need for restarting).

Sometimes it can also have two applications in the same application pool, if they are tightly connected. It could for example be a frontend application, that uses your API application, all the time. In that situation, you can benefit having the applications in the same application  pool, as you then "sync" their recycle times.

The key rule, is to ask yourself: Are these sites the same application, but just different parts of it? And will you always update the two applications at the same time? If you can answer yes to both, when one application pool can be a good choice.

But the general rule, is that you use one pool per site :)

Answer (score 1):

You can put more than one application in the same pool to save resources.

Each application pool is a separate process. If you have a lot of small applications it can make sense to group them in the pools to have less processes running on the server.