# Application pool for each website or few websites in 1 application pool?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have a virtual server (8gb ram, windows server 2008 64bit, 2 core of x5650 2.67ghz) in this server there are more than 35 website of my clients, each website (application pool) take approximately between 80mb to 150mb each.

and I'm going to host more website on this server, but there is a ram limitation..
I tested it and put 6 websites in the same application pool (websites with the same CMS system) and the result is reduce of * 2 less ram

I think about the option to make 5-20 website in the same application pool in order to host more websites, but what is the risk? Is dangerous too much??

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111262/when-do-i-host-different-applications-on-the-same-application-pool-in-iis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main risk is when you have a client that change their pages too often and will in purpose try to create problems to your server, or because is a "bad programmer" and do not release resources and eat all the pools memory.

If for example you have 20 sites under one pool, and one of them is try to crash the pool, or eat all the memory, or in general act with bad intentions, then is going to create problems to all the sites under the same pool.

So you need to monitor that, the pool health, not many restarts, not too much memory, etc, and all of your clients to act normally.

Also there are available hack tools for asp.net but I do not like to mention here and give ideas. Now if a site of you infect by them, ether because a client of you on purpose runs it, ether because a hacker upload them - then all the sites under the same pool can be edited by the user of some other site. Eg, the site A, can edit all the files that exist on the same pool, not easy but can do that.

So to close, you need to make backups, and monitor your user activities for bad behavior.

Comment: Plus any changes which results in application restart i.g. changing `web.config` of one website causes all website sessions be vanished.